# Python not removing item from list when it's in list

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a script that keeps track of lineups for each team in a basketball play-by-play with the end goal of tracking plus/minus by lineup (against each distinct lineup from the opponent). So as I'm iterating through the dataframe, I have a list that keeps track of lineups of the opponent (opp_lineup) and a list of subouts (opp_subouts). Here is the code:

```
if opp_subouts:
    for opp_player in opp_subouts:
        opp_lineup.remove(opp_player)
    opp_subouts = []
```

I had success with this script until I a certain play-by-play. It is giving me an error with the last item in the list (and is on other play-by-plays now), saying it doesn't exist in opp_lineup.

I threw this code first thing in the for loop to troubleshoot:

```
print(opp_player)
print(opp_lineup)
print(opp_player == opp_lineup[-1])
```

Here is the output:

```
#31 NIANGANE
['#04 MCBRIDE', '#11 EFIANAYI', '#20 NELSON', '#21 AHOLODE', '#24 IVEY', '#31 NIANGANE']
True
```

So although the two strings are equal, list.remove(x) won't work and throws an error. What is going on here?

Comment: What's the error thrown?

Comment: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Are you sure opp_player is a string? Try also printing `type(opp_player)`

Comment: Yep, it returns <class 'str'>. It actually removes players in the list BEFORE this, but it seems to consistently throw an error on the last item in the list.

Comment: Do you remove it twice in the loop?

Comment: It's weird. Maybe you need to paste more code.

Comment: It shouldn't be, I just printed out opp_subouts before the removal and there's only one player (as it should be)

Comment: Could it be the fact that opp_player ('#31 NIANGANE') originally starts out as a list that I use  `opp_player = ' '.join(opp_player)` to convert it? I wasn't having this problem until I put that code in, along with changing some regular expressions earlier on in the code (that shouldn't affect this particular string anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing `opp_lineup` from the same scope that the for loop is iterating through? Is there anywhere where you're redefining `opp_lineup` before you're trying to remove something from it? It seems like you're trying to remove the correct `str` but you're trying to remove it from the wrong object.

Comment: I was printing it directly before I tried removing it. That said, I found the error

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems: 1) An error in the source data and 2) an error in a regex that I changed and forgot about that removed suffixes earlier in the code.